# Theorem 4.18 (a), (d), (e) - Rudin's functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

There's a bit which seems to be obvious, but it isn't obvious to me.

> Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach Spaces.

> (a) If $T \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ and $\text{dim  } \mathcal{R}(T) < \infty$ then
> $T$ is compact.

> (d) If $T \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, $T$ is compact and $\lambda \neq 0$ then $\text{dim   } \mathcal{N}(T - \lambda I) < \infty$.

> (e) if $\text{dim   } X < \infty$, $T \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, and $T$ is compact, then $0 \in \sigma(T)$.

My attempt for (a)

If $\left\{ x_k \right\}$ is a bounded sequence in $X$ then $Tx_k$ is bounded as well, this follows from

$$
\left\lVert T x_k \right\rVert \leq \left\lVert T \right\rVert \left\lVert x_k \right\rVert
$$

I define therefore the sequence $\left\{ y_k = Tx_k \right\}$ in $\mathcal{R}(T)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ (assuming complex field) but I can extract $y_k$ a convergent subsequence say $y_{k_i}$ but $y_{k_i} = Tx_{k_i}$ so there exists a subsequence of $x_k$ such that the image of such subsequence converges in $\mathcal{R}(T)$ so we're done.

My attempt for (d)

I only struggled to understand why the range of the restrinction is the same set
Suppose $x \in \mathcal{N}(T - \lambda I)$ then we have

$$
Tx - \lambda x = 0 \iff Tx = \lambda x \in \mathcal{N}(T - \lambda I)
$$
(since it is a double implication I guess this proves the range of the restriction is the same set).

My attempt for (e)

I'm not quite sure about this... I think it's simply the contrapositive of (b)

> if $T \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$, $T$ is compact, and $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is closed then $\text{dim   }\mathcal{R}(T) < \infty$.

?

Comment: @Sumanta I do apologize, I literally updated the question while you wrote your comment...

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (e):

- IF $X$ is finite dimensional, then $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $Y$.
- Every finite dimensional subspace of a topological linear space $Y$ (a banach space in particular) is closed, and all finite dimensional spaces of the same dimension are homeomorphic.
- Every linear maps between finite dimensional normed spaces  is continuous.

Comment: The author sais that *it follows from (b) for if $0$ is not in $\sigma(T)$ then $\mathcal{R}(T) = X$*. Does your hint still apply?